# How to adjust a covariate in a paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test?

Tags: random-effects-model, paired-data

I am trying to study the difference in a biomarker (ANG7) levels pre and post bariatric surgery (a weight-loss surgery). I am using paired `Wilcoxon signed-rank test` for this analysis. The test shows there is a significant reduction in ANG7 after the surgery. But the ANG7 is also associated with BMI, so I want to control BMI to say that "there is a significant reduction in ANG7 after the bariatric surgery". My question is, how to control a covariate in a paired data design, what is the appropriate test to do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To account for covariates, use a regression model instead of a statistical test. It turns out that models generalize tests [1, 2]. In your case you would regress post-surgery ANG7 on pre-surgery ANG7 and BMI. Since you want to generalize the Wilcoxon signed-rank test, use ordinal regression (aka proportional odds logistic regression or POLR).

---

*References*

[1] *Biostatistics for Biomedical Research* course notes. Available [online](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/) 
[2] [Inference of nonparametric tests as linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/573260/237901).

More about the covarite BMI:

- Analyze log(BMI) instead of BMI because BMI is a ratio of two quantities, weight and height (squared).
- Even better, if you have those measurements, you can substitute log(BMI) with log(weight) and log(height).